# What does "I'm obligated to pick you up. Is seven ok?" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, jokes

I saw this joke somewhere and couldn't get.
[image]

I searched the words smooth seven and everything on urban dictionary but still couldn't figure out!

Comment: "Can I pick you up at seven o'clock?" - "You are a cunning man!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pick up trash, you pick it and dispose of it properly, like in a trash can. However, *pick up* also has another meaning:

> [pick up](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pick-up)
>   [transitive] to go and meet someone or something that you have arranged to take somewhere in a vehicle
>   *Will you pick me up after the party?*
>   *I need to pick up my luggage before leaving.*

It is often used to confirm a romantic date, as in

> How about dinner tonight? I'll pick you up around seven (o'clock).

In other words, the second comment was a [pick-up line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick-up_line) used to ask the other person out on a date. "Is seven okay?" means "Is seven **o'clock** okay?", or "Can I pick you up at seven o'clock?"

The third comment, "you smooth fucker", is acknowledging that the other person was skillful, suave  and that the pick-up line was clever.